# Prove That 2 Vectors are Perpendicular Using The Properties of Vectors

Tags: vectors, proof-explanation

This is a practice question I have for a test and have absolutely no idea how to solve...

Given Information:

1) Vector p is a unit vector

2) Vector q is any non-zero vector

3) Vector r = (p dot q)(p)

4) Vector s = q - r

Prove that p and s are perpendicular using the properties of vectors.

Comment: which theorems can you use?

Comment: This is a grade 12 calculus and vectors class, so we only know the basics ie. Cross product, dot product, vector addition and vector subtraction. We havent learned any theorums (yet)

Comment: i would use the dot product

Comment: for 3) its the dot product of p and q multiplied by vector p

Comment: p dot q gives a number

Comment: Try using the fact that the dot product of two perpendicular vectors is 0.  @ShraddheyaShendre that's just p scaled by the dot product.  It doesn't make sense as a triple product.

Comment: i tried using p dot s = 0 and subbing in equations but got nowhere

Comment: By the properties of dot products recognize that $p*s=p*q-p*r$.

Comment: cant believe i didnt see that. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have $$p\cdot s=p\cdot(q-r)=p\cdot (q-(p\cdot q)*p)=p\cdot q-(p\cdot q)*p^2=p\cdot q-p\cdot q=0$$ since $$p^2=1$$ it is a unit vector

Answer (score 0):

If you define $<x,y>$ as the dot product, to show that $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular, you need to show that

$<s,p>=0$

Then, you can plug in the formula that you have for $s$ and use the linearity of dot product, which says

$<\alpha x+\beta y,z>=\alpha<x,z>+\beta <y,z>$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are scalars and $x,y,z$ are vectors.

Hope you are willing to do the rest.